# Three 8-letter words with at least 23 different letters

Tags: wordplay, optimization, letters, wordle

I have literally dozens of wordsets containing 22 different letters, but haven't been able to crack 23, and DEFINITELY not 24. Can you do it?

Here are as many of mine as I feel like posting, to get you motivated (when more than 3 words are in a group, ANY of the initial, similarly spelt words can be combined with the final 2 words to get 22 letters; also, due to my search methodology there're definitely doubles):

udometry
outdream
udometer
flyspeck
whizbang

pyrrhics
whiprays
whispery
shipyard
syrphian
syrphids
physique
judgment
backflow

rowdyish
judgment
backflip

crayfish
grayfish
fortyish
judgment
plowback

flextime
methoxyl
wingback
jodhpurs

plowback
judgment
crayfish

backflow
judgment
whiprays

flyspeck
whizbang
udometry

exordium
outmoved
roqueted
adjustor
dextrous
outdrive
outdrove
outraved
vermouth

rhizopus
viperish
asphyxia
hypoxias
oxyphils
phylaxis
hryvnias
varnishy
pyrexias

hryvnias
varnishy
plowback
judgment

dextrous
whizbang
flyspeck

backflow
wrackful
wreckful
judgment
hypoxias

fireback
backfire
backflow
drawback
backward
backwrap
wrackful
judgment
oxyphils

backflow
cribwork
judgment
phylaxis

squinted
questing
frowzily
humpback

doorjamb
bewormed
biformed
budworms
vexingly
chutzpas/chutzpah

budworms
vexingly
chutzpah
chutzpas

vexingly
buckshot
firedamp

vexingly
jodhpurs
zweiback

mitzvahs
wreckful
epoxying

HAPPY HUNTING

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but this would be much clearer if you said "23 _different_ letters".

Comment: Please define what word set is allowed

Comment: "happy hunting" has only ten different letters!

Comment: @Stef Better count again. :)

Comment: Can apostrophes, hyphens, or accented letters be counted as "letters" for this purpose?

Comment: @dan04 I suppose no. The intent is more on "let's try to cover as much of the alphabet A-Z as possible"

Comment: I hope that the new contributor user87072 understands the voting culture and **accepts** the answer from @DanielMathias which answers the question (mine didn't).

Comment: @WeatherVane Yours was a roundabout way of doing so, but I got the gist. Is it better now?

Comment: Thanks – I didn't provide any 23-letter groups as asked, and my 24-letter offering didn't use dictionary-only words. Hope you enjoy SE Puzzling!

Comment: @bobble YAWL by Mendel Leo Cooper

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Searching a list of over 8000 eight-letter words with no repeated letters yields the following six triples, each with 23 distinct letters:

> flumping skydiver watchbox
>  frowsted humpback vexingly
>  frowzily judgment pushback
>  frumpled joystick whizbang
>  jawboxes mindf**k triglyph
>  longjump skydiver watchbox

Comment: Figuring out on each line which unique letter is doubled is a fun mini-activity in itself, haha

Comment: Two additional ones (with repeated letters) from the 39287 eight-letter words in the YAWL word.list: {fumblers, whipjack, zygodont} and {buckjump, dwarfing, ethoxyls}

Answer (score 8):

Looking for three 8-letter word groups with 24 distinct letters.

I was unable to find a solution in a dictionary, but did find several by using other [word lists](https://www.keithv.com/software/wlist/). Most are 'suspect' but this one uses three words or names that have some currency, there being a Wikipedia entry for each:

> **FAVICONS JEDBURGH MXYZPTLK**
>
>  [FAVICONS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) is a shortcut icon, website icon, etc.
>  [JEDBURGH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedburgh) is a town in Scotland, UK.
>  [MXYZPTLK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Mxyzptlk) is a comic book character.

---

Expanding the search to three 9-letter words (each of which has distinct letters) I found some solutions which don't use proper names. Each of them uses 24 letters, with 3 letters shared:

> depraving schmaltzy squawkbox
>  fletching jumpdrive squawkbox
>  jumpdrive quakingly switchbox
>  pervading schmaltzy squawkbox

The third word used in each of them is a bit suspect though.

Comment: Using fictional names feels a tiny bit like cheating. You could potentially find nearly every combination of letters that way in the thousands of years of recorded history.

Comment: @Nzall that's rather a strawman argument – I didn't. One word is quite contemporary, the fictional character is 20th century, and the town, although old, still stands. They each have a Wikipedia entry so they aren't obscure. I used a selection of [word lists](https://www.keithv.com/software/wlist/). There are no words sets in a conventional dictionary.

Comment: Regardless of the commonality of the proper nouns, in challenges like this, it's typically considered a faux pas to use proper nouns entirely. Although it's never stipulated explicitly in the puzzle brief, you'll notice all of OP's examples don't use proper nouns either.

Comment: (Also, the characters name is Mister Mxyzptlk, not just Mxyzptlk, and since it's a pseudonym and not a real name, using just the 'surname' feels like a doubly faux pas.)

Comment: @TakingNotes as OP knows, there are none to be found in a dictionary, and I don't pretend there were. I took it as a task to find solutions from other word lists, seeing as one answer had already been posted with 23-letter ones. Most of the offerings weren't reasonable to post, and I'm sorry you find this one to be such.

Comment: @WeatherVane with your latest comment included into your answer, I think it'd make a very good answer. As is, it seems claiming that you've found the holy grail, while, based on your comment, it's really "here's what you can do if we use other word lists", with the good reasoning you provide.

Comment: Even using a wordlist provided by Google Books, which I like to use because it is full of typos, combined words, and other OCR hallucinations, I cannot find any sets that have 24 unique letters.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for all, especially the 9-letters! For the Wordle clones I play every morning, I chose my preferred set of 8-letters (flyspeck whizbang outdream) both because they cover the 22 most common letters, AND because each of them are either nouns or verbs which can easily be pluralized/conjugated to flyspecks whizbangs outdreams. Your 24s sure beat my approach of quadrupling up on S's!

Comment: @justhalf I edited (and extended) the answer following your helpful comment.