# Can you employ all 26 letters using three 11-letter, three 10-letter, or three 9-letter words?

Tags: wordplay, optimization, letters, wordle, pangram

I'd like to take the premise of my [previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123394/three-8-letter-words-with-at-least-23-different-letters) (and insofar, only other) post and extend it. Are there any wordsets that cover all 26 letters across...

Three 11-letter words,
Three 10-letter words,
or Three 9-letter words?

My current wordsets include:
11s: Downrightly Lumberjacks (20 letters, missing QZXFVP)
10s: *never attempted*
9s: Depraving Schmaltzy Jukeboxes (23, missing QWF; all suggested 24-letter-spanning wordsets on my previous post contained at least 1 unaccepted word)

EDIT: The bounty for +100 reputation will be issued to the poster who, within the 7-day time frame:

1. Generates 3-word wordlists for all 3 lengths (11-letter, 10-letter, 9-letter).
2. Gets the closest to covering 26 letters with each list, especially 9-letter.
3. I keep forgetting: please use the dictionary provided by YAWL by Mendel Leo Cooper - download [here](https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl/archive/master.zip).

Good luck! Fun Fact (I'm full of these): the Japanese colloquialism for 'good luck' is 頑張って「 ください」  / Ganbatte [Kudasai] / (Please) Do Your Best. I take solace in the idea that good luck isn't a matter of fate, but the intersection of growth mindset and hard work.

Comment: Three 9-letter words is a tall order. I don't know of any pangram with only 1 letter duplicated, let alone in just three words.

Comment: I believe that it is impossible to find three 9-letter words in the English language that contain every single letter of the alphabet. I would be happy for someone to prove me wrong (or right) but I believe it is possible to contain 25-24

Comment: @WeatherVane Waltz Vibex Fjord Chunk Gymps Qi.

Comment: buckjumps wildgrave zanthoxyl -fq

Comment: @user87072 can you please give a source that words must be in, because this trickle of nonce words might turn into flood.

Comment: Since nobody's provided me with those resources, besides URLs to the Wordle clones I play, start with YAWL by Mendel Leo Cooper.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an actual word list?

Comment: I have found a `word.list` file buried in [https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl/archive/master.zip](https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl/archive/master.zip) if that is the one. Can't find any 26-letter solutions for 9, 10 or 11 letter word groups.

Comment: ... even with this "dodgy dictionary". But I found ten 5x5's, one is – clipt jumby kreng vozhd waqfs x. Merriam-Webster has the first three, but not the last two, which are not English language words.

Comment: I compiled a txt file containing all 9 letter words recognized by Merriam Webster. However, proper nouns are included as well (Designated by a capital letter). I also quickly wrote a code but due to the nature of the problem it has a complexity time of O(n^3) and I don't exactly feel like waiting a month. I'm linking a [Git Repository](https://github.com/computer-Goblin/3-Nine-Letter-Pangram.git) so feel free to optimize my code or use the txt file.

Comment: An old wordle meme suggested Glent Brick Jumpy Vozhd Waqfs [x] to "win every time."

Comment: I updated my answer with results obtained by using the YAWL word.list.

Comment: Matt Parker made videos looking at a similar thing with 5-letter words: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-AfhLQfb6w and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c33AZBnRHks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From @computer_goblin's list of 46659 nine-letter words, the maximum number of letters covered by three words is

> 24: bockwurst exemplify Ghaznevid

If you instead consider only the subset of 43098 words that do not contain a capital letter, the maximum is

> 23: bedworthy magnaflux quickstep

I found both sets by solving a [maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem) via integer linear programming, with a binary decision variable $x_w$ to indicate whether word $w$ is selected and a binary decision variable $y_\ell$ to indicate whether letter $\ell$ is covered.  Let $W_\ell$ be the set of words that contain letter $\ell$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_\ell y_\ell$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_w x_w &= 3 \tag1\label1 \\
y_\ell &\le \sum_{w\in W_\ell} x_w &&\text{for all $\ell$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} selects exactly three words.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the logical implication $y_\ell \implies \bigvee_{w\in W_\ell} x_w$.  That is, if letter $\ell$ is covered, then some word $w$ that contains $\ell$ must be selected.

---

By request, here is more detail about the solution process.

Here's the SAS code I used, with more descriptive variable names SelectWord and CoverLetter instead of $x$ and $y$, respectively:

```
data words;
   infile 'Nine Letter Words.txt';
   input word $9.;
run;

proc optmodel;
   /* declare parameters and read data */
   set <str> WORDS;
   read data words into WORDS=[word];
   WORDS = setof {w in WORDS} lowcase(w);
   set LETTERS = setof {k in 97..97+26-1} byte(k);
   set <str> WORDS_l {LETTERS} init {};
   str letterThis;
   for {w in WORDS} do;
      for {k in 1..length(w)} do;
         letterThis = char(w,k);
         WORDS_l[letterThis] = WORDS_l[letterThis] union {w};
      end;
   end;

   /* SelectWord[w] = 1 if word w is selected; 0 otherwise */
   var SelectWord {WORDS} binary;

   /* CoverLetter[l] = 1 if letter l is covered; 0 otherwise */
   var CoverLetter {LETTERS} binary;

   /* maximize the number of letters covered */
   max NumLettersCovered = sum {l in LETTERS} CoverLetter[l];

   /* select exactly three words */
   con Cardinality:
      sum {w in WORDS} SelectWord[w] = 3;

   /* if CoverLetter[l] = 1 then SelectWord[w] = 1 for some word w that contains letter l */ 
   con LetterImpliesWord {l in LETTERS}:
      CoverLetter[l] <= sum {w in WORDS_l[l]} SelectWord[w];

   /* call MILP solver */
   solve;

   /* display selected words */
   put ({w in WORDS: SelectWord[w].sol > 0.5});
quit;
```

And here is the resulting log:

```
NOTE: There were 46659 observations read from the data set WORK.WORDS.
NOTE: Problem generation will use 4 threads.
NOTE: The problem has 46683 variables (0 free, 0 fixed).
NOTE: The problem has 46683 binary and 0 integer variables.
NOTE: The problem has 27 linear constraints (26 LE, 1 EQ, 0 GE, 0 range).
NOTE: The problem has 390770 linear constraint coefficients.
NOTE: The problem has 0 nonlinear constraints (0 LE, 0 EQ, 0 GE, 0 range).
NOTE: The OPTMODEL presolver is disabled for linear problems.
NOTE: The initial MILP heuristics are applied.
NOTE: The MILP presolver value AUTOMATIC is applied.
NOTE: The MILP presolver removed 0 variables and 0 constraints.
NOTE: The MILP presolver removed 50163 constraint coefficients.
NOTE: The MILP presolver modified 0 constraint coefficients.
NOTE: The presolved problem has 46683 variables, 27 constraints, and 340607 constraint
      coefficients.
NOTE: The MILP solver is called.
NOTE: The parallel Branch and Cut algorithm is used.
NOTE: The Branch and Cut algorithm is using up to 4 threads.
          Node   Active   Sols    BestInteger      BestBound      Gap    Time
             0        1      3     17.0000000     24.4187817   30.38%       0
NOTE: The MILP solver's symmetry detection found 31186 orbits. The largest orbit contains 28
      variables.
             0        1      4     20.0000000     24.4187817   18.10%       0
             0        1      4     20.0000000     24.3769559   17.96%       0
             0        1      4     20.0000000     24.3474535   17.86%       1
             0        1      4     20.0000000     24.3403990   17.83%       1
             0        1      4     20.0000000     24.3230216   17.77%       1
             0        1      4     20.0000000     24.3018657   17.70%       1
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.3018657   13.59%       1
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2928681   13.55%       1
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2719184   13.48%       2
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2474321   13.39%       2
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2403600   13.37%       2
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2295855   13.33%       3
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2221405   13.30%       3
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2185102   13.29%       3
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2137198   13.27%       4
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2114068   13.26%       4
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2095593   13.26%       5
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2045244   13.24%       6
             0        1      5     21.0000000     24.2010946   13.23%       6
NOTE: The MILP solver added 13 cuts with 601893 cut coefficients at the root.
             1        2      5     21.0000000     24.2010946   13.23%       7
             9        8      6     23.0000000     24.1990119    4.95%       8
            13        2      6     23.0000000     24.1519567    4.77%       8
            58        0      7     24.0000000     24.0000000    0.00%       8
NOTE: Optimal.
NOTE: Objective = 24.
```

- The Node column reports the number of (non-root) branch-and-bound nodes in the search tree.  Node 0 is the root.
- The Active column reports the number of active nodes in the tree.
- The Sols column reports the number of integer feasible solutions found so far.
- The BestInteger column reports the objective value of the best integer feasible solution found so far and is a lower bound on the global maximum.
- The BestBound column reports the best upper bound found so far; in particular, the first value 24.4187817 is the optimal objective value of the linear programming relaxation.
- The Gap column reports the optimality gap, that is, relative difference between these lower and upper bounds.
- The Time column reports the number of seconds that have elapsed.

In case it helps your understanding, here are the nonzero parts of an optimal LP solution that yields objective value 24.4187817 and satisfies all variable bounds and linear constraints but violates integrality:

```
w         SelectWord[w] 
backswamp 0.129019 
backvelds 0.117597 
blitzweed 0.033418 
byproduct 0.096447 
dezinkify 0.096024 
egyptized 0.040609 
fauxhawks 0.358714 
fevertwig 0.055415 
flapjacks 0.091794 
flaxbirds 0.129442 
ghaznavid 0.217851 
jarovized 0.236464 
jumpingly 0.435279 
objectify 0.236464 
pibloktoq 0.069797 
prongbuck 0.046531 
sixtyfold 0.032149 
verklempt 0.090525 
vetchworm 0.282149 
whizbangs 0.141286 
zygantrum 0.063029 

l CoverLetter[l] 
a 1.000000 
b 1.000000 
c 1.000000 
d 1.000000 
e 1.000000 
f 1.000000 
g 1.000000 
h 1.000000 
i 1.000000 
j 1.000000 
k 1.000000 
l 1.000000 
m 1.000000 
n 1.000000 
o 1.000000 
p 1.000000 
q 0.069797 
r 1.000000 
s 1.000000 
t 1.000000 
u 1.000000 
v 1.000000 
w 1.000000 
x 0.520305 
y 1.000000 
z 0.828680
```

The branch-and-bound algorithm would choose some fractional variable, say SelectWord[backswamp] = 0.129019, and "branch" on that variable, that is, create two child nodes, one with SelectWord[backswamp] = 0 and one with SelectWord[backswamp] = 1.  It would then choose one of those nodes, solve the LP, and repeat the process.  Branch-and-bound is a recursive "divide and conquer" tree search, where the tree is dynamically constructed as needed.

---

Here are optimal results obtained with word.list as the dictionary.

The maximum coverage from the 26649 eleven-letter words is

> 24: buckjumping reflexivity schwarzlots

The maximum coverage from the 33679 ten-letter words is

> 24: buckjumped flyweights overtaxing

The maximum coverage from the 38318 nine-letter words is

> 24: buckjumps wildgrave zanthoxyl

The maximum coverage from all 264097 words is

> 25: exemplificative jawbreakingly soliloquized

which you can also achieve by restricting to words that have at most eleven letters:

> 25: buckjumped overflowing zanthoxyls

---

Here are optimal results obtained with word.list as the dictionary, excluding buckjump* and zanthoxyl*.

The maximum coverage from the eleven-letter words is

> 24: frankpledge objectivize sympathique

The maximum coverage from the ten-letter words is

> 24: jackknifed playwright squeezebox

The maximum coverage from the nine-letter words is

> 23: foxgloves whipjacks zygantrum

The maximum coverage from all words is

> 25: exemplificative hydrogenizes kabeljouw

which you can also achieve by restricting to words that have at most eleven letters:

> 25: jumboizing paddywhacks reflexivity

Comment: fascinating. What do I need in order to run ILP? MatLAB?

Comment: @JLee There are many commercial and open-source ILP solvers. I use SAS.

Comment: Thx. How long did the code run in order to search all 16,928,836,312,609 combinations? Or did it somehow trim that down to a smaller number?

Comment: It took only a few seconds.  ILP does not explicitly enumerate all 3-subsets.  Instead, it first solves the linear programming (LP) relaxation obtained by ignoring integrality (here, replacing the binary restrictions $\{0,1\}$ with $[0,1]$).  Then it performs a tree search ("branch and bound"), with the LP relaxation as the root node of the tree.

Comment: Hard for me to understand how the answer can be found without considering every possibility. I looked into ILP today, but it all seems like theory and summaries. How do you feed it that massive wordlist? Could you elaborate on the solving process, both yours and the stuff under the hood?

Comment: @JLee I added more details to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It will take quite some time for me to absorb this, I'm sure.

Comment: Glad to help.  I added even more detail just now, explicitly displaying the (fractional) LP solution.

Comment: These are great, thanks for your hard coding work. Two questions: 1. Are there any runners up? Because...

Comment: 2. No variation of "buckjump" came up as valid. I ask as a total novice and recognize my risk of sounding ungrateful, but is there any way to remove all "buckjump"s from results? (While we're at it, my wordle clones also didn't take schwarzlots, wildgrave, nor zanthoxyl[s], which of course means that the 9-letter list was a total wash for me.)

Comment: @user87072 I added new results just now.

Answer (score 1):

My answer uses words with **distinct letters** in each (a condition of the previous puzzle) so as not to repeat the findings of another answer, which allows duplicated letters. Obviously there must be duplicated letters *shared* by words. Using the YAWL dictionary as asked.

I can only find **24 letters** using 3 words.

> 9-letter words, only one solution:
>  buckjumps wildgrave zanthoxyl
>
>  10-letter words, only one solution:
>  buckwheats complexify jargonized
>
>  11-letter words: no solutions.
>
>  9, 10 and 11-letter words, some of the 117 solutions are:
>  backfired showjumping vexatiously
>  downmarket flexography subvocalize
>  subjectify vulgarized workmanship

I can get **25 letters** by using 4 words of length 7 (total 28).

> Some of the 119 solutions are:
>  blocked jewfish quartzy vamping
>  cowflap dryings jukebox mitzvah
>  jukebox swiftly vamping zorched

I can get **all 26 letters** by going to 4 words of length 8 (total 32).

> The 28 solutions are:
>  backflow hexapody jerquing mitzvahs
>  backflow jerquing mythized poxvirus
>  backflow jodhpurs mezquits vexingly
>  biforked mezquits vexingly whipjack
>  biformed mezquits vexingly whipjack
>  biformed quartzes vexingly whipjack
>  biformed quetzals vexingly whipjack
>  bodysurf mezquits vexingly whipjack
>  clangbox fervidly mezquits whipjack
>  convexly jumboize prefight squawked
>  defuzing movables quixotry whipjack
>  detoxify jerquing mitzvahs plowback
>  detoxify overjump quackles whizbang
>  dewaxing jackfish mezquits provably
>  emboxing fervidly mezquits whipjack
>  emboxing fervidly quartzes whipjack
>  emboxing fervidly quetzals whipjack
>  emboxing flypitch jarovize squawked
>  fibrosed mezquits vexingly whipjack
>  flowback hexapody jerquing mitzvahs
>  flowback jerquing mythized poxvirus
>  flowback jodhpurs mezquits vexingly
>  forbidal mezquits vexingly whipjack
>  fordable mezquits vexingly whipjack
>  jovialty quadplex wharfing zambucks
>  joystick quadplex vasiform whizbang
>  joystick quadplex waveform whizbang
>  mezquits unforbid vexingly whipjack

I can also get **all 26 letters** from 5 words of length 6 (total 30).

> Some of the many solutions are:
>  abject fluxed moving squawk zephyr
>  abrupt faxing qualmy vozhds wejack
>  aching folksy jawbox quartz vamped

Method: exhaustive recursion with the search space reduced by
a) using unique letters in each word reduces the dictionary size
b) not proceeding when there can't be enough letters remaining