Can you use all 26 letters across four 7-letter words?
I'm wondering if there's a set of four 7-letter words that employ all 26 English letters. That's 28 letters total, allowing for 2 duplicates. I would even count getting 25 a win (see below for my 22- to 24-letter sets). Please use YAWL for the wordlist. Some of my by-hand (and stolen) attempts [with letters missed] include:

Trypsin Daglock Jewfish Overmix [BZQU]
Trypsin Daglock Jewfish Bezique [VMX]
Frankly Mezquit Jodhpur Waxings [BCV]
Bravely Muzjiks Fowlpox Thonged [CQ]
Bravely Muzjiks Fowlpox Ducting [HQ]
Bravely Muzjiks Fowlpox Cantdog [HQ]


@bobble See my only other post. Puzzle-creation was suggested; I'm new, so I's just followin' orders.

This seems to mostly be a request to write code for a specific task.

If you count 25 letters as a win,

 Some of the 119 solutions I found are:
 blocked jewfish quartzy vamping [X]
 cowflap dryings jukebox mitzvah [Q]
 jukebox swiftly vamping zorched [Q]

Here, none of the words has any duplicate letter itself.
Edit: the previous 119 solutions with no letter duplications in any word.

 avyzing boxfish lockjaw trumped  -q
 avyzing cutwork foxship jumbled  -q
 avyzing dropfly jambeux thwacks  -q
 avyzing frichts jukebox wimpled  -q
 avyzing jumbled postfix whacker  -q
 avyzing jumbled postfix whicker  -q
 avyzing jumbler postfix whacked  -q
 bedwarf gazumps jonquil kvetchy  -x
 blocked jewfish quartzy vamping  -x
 blowzed faquirs jumping kvetchy  -x
 boxfish delving pickmaw quartzy  -j
 boxfish devling pickmaw quartzy  -j
 boxfish jacking quartzy wimpled  -v
 boxfish jangled pickmaw quartzy  -v
 boxfish jingled pickmaw quartzy  -v
 boxfish jocking quartzy wimpled  -v
 boxfish jumping quartzy wedlock  -v
 boxfish jungled pickmaw quartzy  -v
 boxfish quartzy vacking wimpled  -j
 boxfish quartzy vamping wedlock  -j
 boxfuls jacking mitzvah powdery  -q
 boxfuls jacking quartzy whomped  -v
 boxfuls jacking quartzy whumped  -v
 boxfuls jocking mitzvah powdery  -q
 boxfuls jocking quartzy whomped  -v
 boxfuls jocking quartzy whumped  -v
 boxfuls jumping kvetchy wizards  -q
 boxfuls jumping quartzy whacked  -v
 boxfuls quartzy vacking whomped  -j
 boxfuls quartzy vacking whumped  -j
 boxfuls quartzy vamping whacked  -j
 britzka complex jewfish ungyved  -q
 bruxing dropfly mitzvah wejacks  -q
 buxomly howfing jetpack vizards  -q
 bywords fluxing jetpack mitzvah  -q
 bywords fluxing mitzvah pajocke  -q
 cashbox muzjiks perving twyfold  -q
 cashbox muzjiks preving twyfold  -q
 cawings dropfly jukebox mitzvah  -q
 chametz dropfly jukebox wavings  -q
 chametz dwarves flyping jukebox  -q
 chametz flyping jukebox swarved  -q
 chawing dropfly jukebox zemstva  -q
 chawing dropfly jukebox zemstvo  -q
 chewing dropfly jukebox zemstva  -q
 chinwag dropfly jukebox zemstva  -q
 chinwag dropfly jukebox zemstvo  -q
 chometz dropfly jukebox wavings  -q
 chometz dwarves flyping jukebox  -q
 chometz flyping jukebox swarved  -q
 chowder flyping jukebox zemstva  -q
 chowing dropfly jukebox zemstva  -q
 clyping jukebox mitzvah swarfed  -q
 clyping jukebox wharfed zemstva  -q
 clyping jukebox wharfed zemstvo  -q
 cowards flyping jukebox mitzvah  -q
 cowflap droving jukebox zythums  -q
 cowflap dryings jukebox mitzvah  -q
 cowflap jambeux kything vizards  -q
 cowherd flyping jukebox zemstva  -q
 crazing jukebox twyfold vampish  -q
 cyprids flawing jukebox mitzvah  -q
 cyprids flowing jukebox mitzvah  -q
 cyprids fowling jukebox mitzvah  -q
 cyprids jukebox mitzvah wolfing  -q
 delving foxship qwertys zambuck  -j
 devling foxship qwertys zambuck  -j
 diptych farebox muzjiks wolving  -q
 driveby foxhunt gazumps lockjaw  -q
 dropfly hawbuck mezquit vexings  -j
 dropfly jukebox mitzvah scowing  -q
 dropfly jukebox mitzvah sowcing  -q
 dropfly jukebox schmalz vawting  -q
 dropfly jukebox schmelz vawting  -q
 droving jewfish planxty zambuck  -q
 expugns lockjaw thrived zombify  -q
 filberd hypoxic muzjiks vawting  -q
 filched jukebox qwertys vamping  -z
 fixedly muzjiks pibroch vawting  -q
 fjordic gazumps hawkbit vixenly  -q
 flexing jodhpur qwertys zambuck  -v
 flocked jambeux vawting zephyrs  -q
 fluxing jodhpur qwertys zambuck  -v
 flyping jambeux thwacks vizored  -q
 flyping jukebox mitzvah scowder  -q
 fopling jambeux kvetchy wizards  -q
 foxings jirbled mitzvah wickyup  -q
 foxship jacking quartzy wambled  -v
 foxship jacking quartzy wimbled  -v
 foxship jambing quartzy wedlock  -v
 foxship jangled qwertys zambuck  -v
 foxship jingled qwertys zambuck  -v
 foxship jocking quartzy wambled  -v
 foxship jocking quartzy wimbled  -v
 foxship jumbled quartzy vacking  -w
 foxship jumbled quartzy wacking  -v
 foxship jumbled qwertys vacking  -z
 foxship jungled qwertys zambuck  -v
 foxship quartzy vacking wambled  -j
 foxship quartzy vacking wimbled  -j
 frowned glyphic jukebox zemstva  -q
 frumped jukebox wavings zlotych  -q
 hutzpas jackleg mixdown verbify  -q
 jambeux twifold vacking zephyrs  -q
 jambeux twyfold vacking zephyrs  -q
 jodhpur swiftly vexings zambuck  -q
 jodhpur twyfold vexings zambuck  -q
 jukebox machzor pavings twyfold  -q
 jukebox perfidy schmalz vawting  -q
 jukebox perfidy schmelz vawting  -q
 jukebox perving schmalz twyfold  -q
 jukebox preving schmalz twyfold  -q
 jukebox proving schmalz twyfold  -q
 jukebox scherzi twyfold vamping  -q
 jukebox scherzo twyfold vamping  -q
 jukebox swarfed vamping zlotych  -q
 jukebox swiftly vamping zorched  -q
 jukebox twyfold vamping zorches  -q
 lockjaw provend quights zombify  -x

And here is the frequency of the missing letter

 q 78
 v 22
 j 12
 x 4
 z 2
 w 1


I believe that you posted this reply on another post when my previous account asked a similar question. Could you please possibly post that list of 119 in full, alongside the 8-letter word sets mentioned above? Thanks!

I will later, but at the mo the search is considering duplicate letters in a word to hopefully find 26 in all :) Note that the previous question does list all the 28 eight-letter words containing the whole alphabet.

You're a rock star! Much appreciated. For me: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123459/can-you-employ-all-26-letters-using-three-11-letter-three-10-letter-or-three-9

(+1) I confirm your count of solutions that use only words without duplicate letters.

I found no full-alphabet solutions even with letters duplicated in any word. Added the previous 25-letter solutions with no duplications.

What do you mean by that comment? The 119-list has those.

Via integer linear programming (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/123475/65277), I found that the maximum is

 25.

There are 515 such optimal solutions, such as:

 avyzing fowlpox jumbuck threads


I confirm that there are no full-alphabet solutions even with letters duplicated in any word.

Thank you. Is there any possibility of posting here (or messaging me) the full list?

Unfortunately there are none that employ all 26 letters.
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var words = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\pse\\yawl-master\\yawl-master\\yawl-0.3.2.03\\word.list")
                    .Where(w => w.Length == 7 && new HashSet<char>(w).Count >= 5)
                    .Select<string, (string word, int mask)>(w => new(w, CreateBitmask(w)))
                    .ToArray();

    int targetMask = (1 << 26) - 1;

    int mj, mk, m;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 3; i++)
    {
        if (i % 1000 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.Length - 2; j++)
        {
            mj = words[i].mask | words[j].mask;
            if (BitsSet(mj) < 12)
            {
                continue;
            }
            for (int k = j + 1; k < words.Length - 1; k++)
            {
                mk = mj | words[k].mask;
                if (BitsSet(mk) < 19)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                for (int l = k + 1; l < words.Length; l++)
                {
                    m = mk | words[l].mask;
                    if (m == targetMask)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{words[i].word} {words[j].word} {words[k].word} {words[l].word}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

static int CreateBitmask(string word)
{
    int bitmask = 0;
    foreach (char c in word)
    {
        bitmask |= 1 << (c - 'a');
    }
    return bitmask;
}

// hamming weight
static int BitsSet(int i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}


Shame. Thanks for all!

Could you post both sets of results (with and without doubled letters)?
