Perfect Pangram development
I aim to craft very specific "perfect pangrams." A perfect pangram consists of exactly 26 letters, each used once. I include the letter lengths of each word, as well, between slashes \# #\:

Bank Vext Quiz Cwms Fjord Glyph \4 4 4 4 5 5\

Ox Qs Gyp Cwm Hadj Verb Link Futz \2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4\

Ex Qs Zip Vug Cwm Nth Balky Fjord \2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5\

Adz Jig Suq Pyx Cwm Nth Verb Folk \3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4\

Qs Kaf Red Zig Job Luv Pyx Cwm Nth \2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3\


As you can see, many of the ones I've written are comprised of short words. What I'm hoping to uncover are very specific PP sets which include longer words:

\3 3 5 5 5 5\

\6 6 7 7\

\5 5 8 8\

\4 4 9 9\


As the words get longer, my expectation that they can be achieved drops, as there are only so many vowels (6) and vowelless, unique letter words to make up for it (Cwm Nth Pht Pst Tsk Cwms Crwth Crwths). Please use YAWL for the wordlist.
I've gotten close with each of these, but always have to include an additional word, leading to an imperfect pangram.

Ave Mix Bop Quaky Fjeld Zings Crwth (MVP Box would've worked, had MVP not been an unaccepted initialism)

Quartz Deluxe Blocky Vamping Jewfish

Wharf Bring Quadplex Zemstvos Joystick

Quad Wife Schmaltzy Depriving Jukeboxes



Is this a puzzle or programmer recruitment?

It is prep for a puzzle.

FWIW I get no results for '6 6 7 7' or '5 5 8 8' or '4 4 9 9' (assuming my code is correct). The '3 3 5 5 5 5' will take a bit longer.

@WeatherVane are you using Knuth's Algorithm-X?

here's one? jerquing pyx vozhd flab tsk cwm

am running it now again, this time without stopping at first solution. Will run overnight, and perhaps for part of tomorrow.

The question begins with "perfect pangrams" but loses focus at the end by including imperfect pangrams, as if inviting solutions for those, which distracts from what seems to be a request for four specific sets of true pangrams, by word length. There are loads of imperfect pangrams, such as "the five boxing wizards jump quickly", which is the shortest pangram I know that actually makes sense.

@WeatherVane I was simply showing my own legwork, proving that I made attempts before requesting assistance. I even explicitly stipulate that I was always forced to dilute the perfection of my pangrams.

@micsthepick Success?

@WeatherVane As a noob, I'd characterize my voting as "minimalist" and "wildly ignorant" before "mean."

@FriskyDingo I found all the perfect pangrams, of any size, yes, but I don't think it has much to add than the existing answers

I found no pangrams for the requested '6 6 7 7' or '5 5 8 8' or '4 4 9 9'.
My answer for '3 3 5 5 5 5' using self-made code is

 11 solutions:
 fix lbw gecks jumpy tranq vozhd
 gju pyx flick tranq vozhd wembs
 gju vox blitz dreck nymph waqfs
 jib pyx kreng mulct vozhd waqfs
 jig pyx crumb knelt vozhd waqfs
 jud vex brock glitz nymph waqfs
 jug pyx flick tranq vozhd wembs
 jug vox blitz dreck nymph waqfs
 jun kex climb grypt vozhd waqfs
 jut pyx climb kreng vozhd waqfs
 pyx viz crwth fjeld gambs quonk


Update
I found 404838 perfect pangrams from the YAWL word list.
Here are some stats:

YAWL has 264097 words, 48852 with unique letters, 36296 excluding anagrams
Most anagrams: there are 13 anagrams of "alerts", "apers" and "arets"
Most words: 9 such as "dzo fy gju hm lbw pranck qi st vex"
Least words: 5 such as "goldbricks jynx putz vehm waqf"
Longest word: "goldbricks", the only 10-letter word, appearing only once

I excluded anagrams until output, when each 'sentence' was permuted to cover them.
As you see, there are no four-word perfect pangrams.
I then rated each pangram according to the frequency that each of its words appears in the lists obtained from Keith Vertanen. The highest scoring pangram was

 cwm fad jog lynx ph quiz tsk verb

so good luck with finding a nice perfect pangram!
The complete pangram list is available (for now) on Microsoft Onedrive.

Using my own implementation, I can confirm the 404838 number is indeed correct.

Via integer linear programming (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/123475/65277), here are the largest numbers of covered letters.
3 3 5 5 5 5

 26:


  {'blitz','dreck','gju','nymph','vox','waqfs'}
  {'blitz','dreck','jug','nymph','vox','waqfs'}
  {'flick','gju','pyx','tranq','vozhd','wembs'}
  {'brock','glitz','jud','nymph','vex','waqfs'}
  {'crumb','jig','knelt','pyx','vozhd','waqfs'}
  {'climb','jut','kreng','pyx','vozhd','waqfs'}
  {'climb','grypt','jun','kex','vozhd','waqfs'}
  {'crwth','fjeld','gambs','pyx','quonk','viz'}
  {'flick','jug','pyx','tranq','vozhd','wembs'}
  {'fix','gecks','jumpy','lbw','tranq','vozhd'}
  {'jib','kreng','mulct','pyx','vozhd','waqfs'}

6 6 7 7

 25:


 {'freckly','jawbox','tumping','vozhds'}
 {'flytrap','jumbuck','vozhds','wexing'}

5 5 8 8

 25:


 {'fumbling','pyrex','stickjaw','vozhd'}
 {'fumbling','prexy','stickjaw','vozhd'}
 {'flowback','jerquing','tymps','vozhd'}
 {'backflow','jerquing','tymps','vozhd'}
 {'jumbling','kvetched','proxy','waqfs'}
 {'fjord','vexingly','whipt','zambucks'}
 {'buckjump','flaxy','strewing','vozhd'}
 {'buckjump','flaxy','vozhd','wresting'}
 {'buckjump','flytings','rewax','vozhd'}
 {'buckjump','flytings','vozhd','waxer'}
 {'buckjump','swerf','taxingly','vozhd'}

4 4 9 9

 25:


 {'blackdamp','frowziest','jynx','vugh'}
 {'buckjumps','lynx','overdight','waqf'}
 {'drumbling','fozy','vext','whipjacks'}
 {'buckjumps','dragonfly','vext','whiz'}

